# Groovy: How to define a java callable with parameters and make it available to groovy shell?

Tags: java, groovy, language-interoperability

I would like to implement a Groovy interface that takes parameters and returns a result in java and make it available in GroovyShell. However Callable, GroovyCallacble do not take any parameters so they are wrong for my purposes.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a "Closure" sub class in java and bind it to the Bindings accompanying a GroovyShell. Once this is done it is possible to execute the Closure from groovy at the bound name.

Comment: Is this part of the same question?  Or are you answering your own question?  If it's part of the same, maybe editing your original Q rather than posting an answer would be more sensible?